# tryCatch in R not working properly

Tags: r, try-catch

I have the following R code:

```
tryCatch( {pre_symbol=read.table(file=filePre,header=FALSE,sep=",")}
         , error = function(e) {loadError = TRUE} )
```

When the input file (filePre) is empty, the tryCatch does NOT set the global variable loadError to TRUE. This creates problems in my code (when code that executes when loadError==false assumes filePre is not empty) that the tryCatch was supposed to prevent. However, when I remove the tryCatch statement and try to load via read.Table, I get the error

> Error in read.table(file = filePre, header = FALSE, sep = ",") :    no
>   lines available in input

which is expected in this case. I have no idea why this isn't working. It works for most of the other files in my set.

Comment: It's bad form to title your question "XXX not working properly," which implies a bug in XXX.  Better to write "Don't understand what I did wrong with XXX"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use global assignment  operator `<<-` here , for example:

```
loadError = FALSE
toto <- function(){

  tryCatch(stop("dummy error"),error=function(e)loadError <<- TRUE)
}

> toto()
> loadError
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This fixed the issue! All these posts were helpful however! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Some alternatives to avoid using "global assignment" (it's not really global except in specific circumstances):

Using exists:

```
tryCatch({
    stop("Error")
    pre_symbol <- "blah"
}, error = function(e) {
    print(e)
})

if(exists("pre_symbol")){
    print(pre_symbol)
}
```

Using NULL:

```
pre_symbol <- NULL
tryCatch({
    stop("Error")
    pre_symbol <- "blah"
}, error = function(e) {
    print(e)
})

if(!is.null(pre_symbol)){
    print(pre_symbol)
}
```

Using options:

```
options(myLoadError=FALSE)
tryCatch({
    stop("Error")
    pre_symbol <- "blah"
}, error = function(e) {
    print(e)
    options(myLoadError=TRUE)
})

if(!isTRUE(getOption("myLoadError"))){
    print(pre_symbol)
}
```

Using environments:

```
loadErrors <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
tryCatch({
    stop("Error")
    pre_symbol <- "blah"
}, error = function(e) {
    print(e)
    loadErrors[["pre_symbol"]] <- TRUE
})

if(!isTRUE(loadErrors[["pre_symbol"]])){
    print(pre_symbol)
}
```

Personally I tend to use the NULL pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Although `<<-` works for sure, but it's not always a good idea to mess with `GlobalEnv`. Why not check for the error and update `loadError` if something went wrong -- outside of the anonymous function without possibly screwing up something in the top-level environment:

```
loadError <- inherits(tryCatch({
    pre_symbol = read.table(file = filePre, header = FALSE, sep = ",")
}, error = function(e) e), 'error')
```

Comment: It's not explicitly global as per documentation: `The operators <<- and ->> are normally only used in functions, and cause a search to made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned` so `myLoadError <<- TRUE` in the error closure is more like `assign("myLoadError",TRUE,pos=1)`

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the try() function:

```
pre_symbol <- try(read.table(file=filePre,header=FALSE,sep=","))
loadError <- is(pre_symbol, 'try-error')
```

Comment: There is a type in the code (I guess). It should be:
`loadError <- is(pre_symbol, 'try-error')`